# GetFocus() returns null for MS Word

Tags: delphi, winapi, window-functions, window-handles

I am writing a Keyboard application that hooks the keyboard and remaps the keys. For this, I have created two projects, one .exe and .dll. In the .dll project, I detect the Handle of the Window in which the user is typing by GetFocus(). However, it works fine in notepad, but not in MS Word since I am not able to get the Window's Handle for the MS Word, using GetFocus()

I understand, that is because it might be running under different thread and hence, I need to get the Parent Window Handle by GetForegroundWindow() and iterate through its child windows and somehow get the right Handle.
While searching on internet I found following code (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34752/Control-in-Focus-in-Other-Processes)

```
activeWindowHandle:= GetForegroundWindow();
activeWindowThread:= GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindowHandle, 0);
thisWindowThread:= GetWindowThreadProcessId(lpHookRec^.TheHookHandle, 0);
AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, true);
lpHookRec^.TheAppWinHandle:= GetFocus();
AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, false);
```

However, it is not working for me :(

In my code I have written

```
lpHookRec^.TheAppWinHandle := GetFocus();
```

and that gives me the Handle of the NotePad window in lpHookRec^.TheAppWinHandle. However, if I use MS Word instead of NotePad, the above code gives me null(zero). So need to write function that returns the correct Handle, irrespective of thread it is running under, something like

```
function GetAppliWinHandle: Hwnd;
  var
    activeWindowHandle,activeWindowThread,thisWindowThread,focusedControlHandle: Hwnd;
  begin { GetAppliWinHandle }
    focusedControlHandle := GetFocus();
    if focusedControlHandle = 0 then
      begin
        activeWindowHandle := GetForegroundWindow();
        activeWindowThread := GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindowHandle, 0);
        thisWindowThread := GetWindowThreadProcessId(lpHookRec^.TheHookHandle, 0);
        AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, true);
        focusedControlHandle := GetFocus();
        AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, false);
      end;
    Result:=focusedControlHandle
  end; { GetAppliWinHandle }
```

and here is the complete code for the dll

```
library TheHook;

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils;

{Define a record for recording and passing information process wide}
type
  PHookRec = ^THookRec;
  THookRec = packed record
    TheHookHandle: HHOOK;
    TheAppWinHandle: HWND;
    TheCtrlWinHandle: HWND;
    TheKeyCount: DWORD;
  end;

var
  hObjHandle: THandle; {Variable for the file mapping object}
  lpHookRec: PHookRec; {Pointer to our hook record}

procedure MapFileMemory(dwAllocSize: DWORD);
begin
  {Create a process wide memory mapped variable}
  hObjHandle := CreateFileMapping($FFFFFFFF, nil, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, dwAllocSize,
    'HookRecMemBlock');
  if (hObjHandle = 0) then
  begin
    MessageBox(0, 'Hook DLL', 'Could not create file map object', MB_OK);
    exit;
  end;
  {Get a pointer to our process wide memory mapped variable}
  lpHookRec := MapViewOfFile(hObjHandle, file_MAP_write, 0, 0, dwAllocSize);
  if (lpHookRec = nil) then
  begin
    CloseHandle(hObjHandle);
    MessageBox(0, 'Hook DLL', 'Could not map file', MB_OK);
    exit;
  end;
end;

procedure UnMapFileMemory;
begin
  {Delete our process wide memory mapped variable}
  if (lpHookRec <> nil) then
  begin
    UnMapViewOfFile(lpHookRec);
    lpHookRec := nil;
  end;
  if (hObjHandle > 0) then
  begin
    CloseHandle(hObjHandle);
    hObjHandle := 0;
  end;
end;

function GetHookRecPointer: pointer stdcall;
begin
  {Return a pointer to our process wide memory mapped variable}
  result := lpHookRec;
end;

{The function that actually processes the keystrokes for our hook}

function KeyBoardProc(Code: integer; wParam: integer; lParam: integer): integer;
  stdcall;
  function GetAppliWinHandle: Hwnd;
  var
    activeWindowHandle,activeWindowThread,thisWindowThread,focusedControlHandle: Hwnd;
  begin { GetAppliWinHandle }
    focusedControlHandle := GetFocus();
    if focusedControlHandle = 0 then
      begin
        activeWindowHandle := GetForegroundWindow();
        activeWindowThread := GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindowHandle, 0);
        thisWindowThread := GetWindowThreadProcessId(lpHookRec^.TheHookHandle, 0);
        AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, true);
        focusedControlHandle := GetFocus();
        AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, false);
      end;
    Result:=focusedControlHandle
  end; { GetAppliWinHandle }

var
  KeyUp: bool;
  {Remove comments for additional functionability ... :

  IsAltPressed: bool;
  IsCtrlPressed: bool;
  IsShiftPressed: bool;
  }
begin
  result := 0;
  case Code of
    HC_ACTION:
      begin
        {We trap the keystrokes here}
        {is this a key up message?}
        KeyUp := ((lParam and (1 shl 31)) <> 0);

        {Remove comments for additional functionability ... :

        {is the Alt key pressed}
        if ((lParam and (1 shl 29)) <> 0) then
        begin
          IsAltPressed := TRUE;
        end
        else
        begin
          IsAltPressed := FALSE;
        end;
        {is the Control key pressed}
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) and (1 shl 15)) <> 0) then
        begin
          IsCtrlPressed := TRUE;
        end
        else
        begin
          IsCtrlPressed := FALSE;
        end;
        {if the Shift key pressed}
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) and (1 shl 15)) <> 0) then
        begin
          IsShiftPressed := TRUE;
        end
        else
        begin
          IsShiftPressed := FALSE;
        end;
        }

        {if KeyUp then increment the key count}
        if (KeyUp <> FALSE) then
        begin
          Inc(lpHookRec^.TheKeyCount);
        end;
        case wParam of
          {Was the enter key pressed?}
          VK_RETURN:
            begin
              {if KeyUp}
              if (KeyUp <> FALSE) then
              begin
                {Post a bogus message to the window control in our app}
                PostMessage(lpHookRec^.TheCtrlWinHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, 0, 0);
                PostMessage(lpHookRec^.TheCtrlWinHandle, WM_KEYUP, 0, 0);
              end;
              {if you wanted to swallow the keystroke then return -1, else if you 
want 
                            to allow the keystroke then return 0}
              result := 0;
              exit;
            end; {VK_RETURN}
          {if the left arrow key is pressed then lets play a joke!}
          VK_LEFT:
            begin
              {Get the Handle of the Application Window in lpHookRec^.TheAppWinHandle}
             lpHookRec^.TheAppWinHandle:=GetAppliWinHandle;

              {if KeyUp}
              if (KeyUp <> FALSE) then
              begin
                {Create a UpArrow keyboard event}
                keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0, 0, 0);
                keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
              end;
              {Swallow the keystroke}
              result := -1;
              exit;
            end; {VK_LEFT}
        end; {case wParam}
        {Allow the keystroke}
        result := 0;
      end; {HC_ACTION}
    HC_NOREMOVE:
      begin
        {This is a keystroke message, but the keystroke message has not been removed
             from the message queue, since an application has called PeekMessage() 
            specifying PM_NOREMOVE}
        result := 0;
        exit;
      end;
  end; {case code}
  if (Code < 0) then
    {Call the next hook in the hook chain}
    result := CallNextHookEx(lpHookRec^.TheHookHandle, Code, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure StartKeyBoardHook stdcall;
begin
  {if we have a process wide memory variable and the hook has not already been 
set...}
  if ((lpHookRec <> nil) and (lpHookRec^.TheHookHandle = 0)) then
  begin
    {set the hook and remember our hook handle}
    lpHookRec^.TheHookHandle := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, @KeyBoardProc,
      hInstance, 0);
  end;
end;

procedure StopKeyBoardHook stdcall;
begin
  {if we have a process wide memory variable and the hook has already been set...}
  if ((lpHookRec <> nil) and (lpHookRec^.TheHookHandle <> 0)) then
  begin
    {Remove our hook and clear our hook handle}
    if (UnHookWindowsHookEx(lpHookRec^.TheHookHandle) <> FALSE) then
    begin
      lpHookRec^.TheHookHandle := 0;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure DllEntryPoint(dwReason: DWORD);
begin
  case dwReason of
    Dll_Process_Attach:
      begin
        {if we are getting mapped into a process, then get a pointer to our 
                process wide memory mapped variable}
        hObjHandle := 0;
        lpHookRec := nil;
        MapFileMemory(sizeof(lpHookRec^));
      end;
    Dll_Process_Detach:
      begin
        {if we are getting unmapped from a process then, remove the pointer to 
                our process wide memory mapped variable}
        UnMapFileMemory;
      end;
  end;
end;

exports
  KeyBoardProc name 'KEYBOARDPROC',
  GetHookRecPointer name 'GETHOOKRECPOINTER',
  StartKeyBoardHook name 'STARTKEYBOARDHOOK',
  StopKeyBoardHook name 'STOPKEYBOARDHOOK';

begin
  {set our Dll's main entry point}
  DLLProc := @DllEntryPoint;
  {Call our Dll's main entry point}
  DllEntryPoint(Dll_Process_Attach);

end.
```

Comment: You'll have more information if you check API results. It may be related with the so called *virtualization*, if it's a click-to-run installation.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I am getting null from GetFocus() when the Application is MS Word (I guess, that is because MDI) but everything works fine in Notepad 

I would like to get a reliable method/function that will always give me the handle of the Current Application

Comment: GetFocus returns null, that we understand. Do you know if the thread is even attached? If not, GetFocus will of course return null. That is why you check API results. ... BTW, it's not evident from the question what you are asking..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz

I am writing a Keyboard application, that hooks the keyboard and remaps the keys. It works fine in notepad, but not in MS Word since I am not able to get the Window's Handle for the MS Word, using GetFocus()

I understand, that is because it might be running under different thread and hence, I need to get the Parent Window Handle by GetForegroundWindow() and iterate through its child windows and somehow get the right Handle.

Can you please help by showing me how to write a function that returns the correct Handle, irrespective of thread it is running under?

Comment: I'm not, or no one else for that matter, will try to solve a problem in the comments. Please edit your question to make clear your specific problem. Provide as much information as you can. If that code snippet is irrelevant, remove it. Explain how you cannot get what handle. I don't even understand currently if you can't have the target application's window handle or something else.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz

I have edited the question, please help

Comment: @bhatji - Can you please add the code that is working for Notead too?

Comment: It's still completely unclear, what ultimate problem you are trying to solve, or why you believe that what you are trying to implement is part of that solution. You keep repeating how you want to solve tiny parts of a bigger solution, that probably isn't. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I am simply typing lpHookRec^.TheAppWinHandle := GetFocus(); and it gives me the Handle of the Window (NotePad in this case)

Comment: @bhattji - I give up. Thanks for trying though... Currently I see the following problems regarding the question. 1- In the first paragraph you explain some code that works for Notepad but not MS Word. However you refuse to post the failing code. 2- In the second paragraph you post code that you expect to work. You've been asked to check API results to progress in the direction of finding how it fails. However you refuse to do so. ... Good luck!

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I have tried to write the function, please help me write the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`GetFocus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646294.aspx) documentation:

> Retrieves the handle to the window that has the keyboard focus, **if the window is attached to the calling thread's message queue**.
>
> ...
>
> `GetFocus` returns the window with the keyboard focus for the **current thread's message queue. If GetFocus returns NULL, another thread's queue may be attached to a window that has the keyboard focus**.
>
> Use the `GetForegroundWindow` function to retrieve the handle to the window with which the user is currently working. You can associate your thread's message queue with the windows owned by another thread by using the `AttachThreadInput` function.

You are trying to do this part, but you are not doing it correctly, and you are not checking for errors along the way.   You are also mistakenly using the `HWND` data type for thread IDs, but they are not `HWND`s, they are `DWORD`s instead.

Try something more like this:

```
function GetAppliWinHandle: HWND;
var
  activeWindowHandle: HWND;
  activeWindowThread, thisThread: DWORD;
begin
  Result := GetFocus();
  if Result = 0 then
  begin
    activeWindowHandle := GetForegroundWindow();
    if activeWindowHandle <> 0 then
    begin
      activeWindowThread := GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindowHandle, 0);
      thisThread := GetCurrentThreadId();
      if AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisThread, TRUE) then
      begin
        Result := GetFocus();
        AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisThread, FALSE);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

However, the same documentation *also* says:

> To get the window with the keyboard focus on the foreground queue or the queue of another thread, use the [`GetGUIThreadInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506.aspx) function.

For example:

```
function GetAppliWinHandle: HWND;
var
  activeWindowHandle: HWND;
  activeWindowThread: DWORD;
  gui: TGUIThreadinfo;
begin
  Result := GetFocus();
  if Result = 0 then
  begin
    activeWindowHandle := GetForegroundWindow();
    if activeWindowHandle <> 0 then
    begin
      activeWindowThread := GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindowHandle, 0);
      gui.cbSize := sizeof(gui);
      if GetGUIThreadInfo(activeWindowThread, gui) then
        Result := gui.hwndFocus;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Or simpler:

```
function GetAppliWinHandle: HWND;
var
  gui: TGUIThreadinfo;
begin
  gui.cbSize := sizeof(gui);
  if GetGUIThreadInfo(0, gui) then
    Result := gui.hwndFocus
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks. I tried the first one, and that worked :) I shall try the other two, but  "GUITHREADINFO" is not recognised, which unit do I use? 

Remy you rock :)

Comment: Delphi deeclares `GUITHREADINFO` as `TGUIThreadinfo` instead. I have updated my example.

Comment: The other two are not compiling :( 

(1) I replaced cbize to cbSize 
(2) It gives error "[dcc64 Error] TheHookDll.dpr(136): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical" at  if GetGUIThreadInfo(0, gui) then

Comment: @bhattji I fixed the `cbSize` typo. You should not be getting a type mismatch error, though. The `Windows` unit declares the second parameter as `var TGUIThreadinfo` so it should match what I showed you, and people have been using code like this just fine for years.

Comment: Thanks, it works now :) However, what are the chance of getting the Result:=0 ? here if GetGUIThreadInfo(0, gui) then
    Result := gui.hwndFocus
  else
    Result := 0;